# Linux Shell Script: Save command outputs in variable/file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, telnet

I want to use some output of a command, but I don't know, how I can save the output in a variable or file.

The script is connecting to a specified server via telnet and executes different commands. One command is needed for further commands. Well... I have to save these informations from the command output.

My code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    (
            echo open server portnumber
            sleep 2s
            echo "login username password"
            sleep 1s
            echo "use sid=1"

            CLIENT_LIST=$(echo "clientlist")

            sleep 1s

            echo "clientupdate client_nickname=Administrator"

            for client_id in $(echo $CLIENT_LIST | grep -Eo "clid=[0-9]+" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"); do
                    echo "clientpoke clid=$client_id msg=How\sare\syou!"
                    sleep 1s
            done

            sleep 1s
            echo "logout"
            echo "quit"
    ) | telnet
```

I want to save the output of the command 'clientlist' in a variable or file. A variable would be the best solution. But actually the variable just saves 'clientlist' and not the output of the command. :(

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance! :)

If you want to test it: It's made for TeamSpeak 3 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by this question you mean "I want to run the `clientlist` command on the remote machine, then capture its output to a variable on the local machine", then you can't do this using something like your script. (Note that you script only pipes input into the `telnet` command; `telnet`'s output isn't captured anywhere.)

You'll need to write a script using something like [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), or one of its work-alikes in another language like [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod) or [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html).

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you. I will execute this code 3-times with different commands and will save the output of telnet in files. That's working. I thought there exists a better solution. :(

Answer (score 9):

To run the command 'clientlist' and save the output in a variable:

```
output_var=$(clientlist)
```

In bash or sh, the `$(...)` syntax means "run this command and return whatever output it produces."